# ERROR 1070: Could not resolve ToDate using imports

Tags: apache-pig

Following are the details:

date2.txt

```
B02617,2/27/2015,1551,14677
B02598,2/27/2015,1114,10755
B02512,2/27/2015,272,2056
B02764,2/27/2015,4253,38780
```

pig-script:

```
A = Load '/files/date2.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (base:chararray, tripdate:chararray, cars:int, tripkms:int);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE tripdate;

C = FOREACH B GENERATE ToDate(tripdate,'yyyy-MM-dd') as mytripdate;
```

This the error I am getting:

> main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve ToDate using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Comment: Any chances you're using very old Pig version?  Not sure why it cannot find ToDate builtin UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input date format is `MM/dd/yyyy`.

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE ToDate(tripdate,'MM/dd/yyyy') as mytripdate;
```

If you want the date to be in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format use `ToString()`

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE ToString(ToDate(tripdate,'MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd') as mytripdate;
```